# How did House Deneith prevent mass losses?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, eberron

In Eberron during "The Last War" House Deneith, like all dragonmarked houses, remained neutral and sold their services to the highest bidders. But as mercenaries/soldiers this could lead to some unique problems.

While I'm sure House Deneith mercs were expensive, at times it could potentially be more cost efficient to lose them than a country's own citizens/soldiers they'd spent time/$ training and which would still be needed later in the war.

**Therefore, if presented a situation where heavy losses would be expected (think D-Day or worse) could they/were they ever ordered to (near) certain death? Was there some sort of financial penalty for mass losses?** (This is the only penalty I can think of to prevent such tactics.) For normal mercs this would sound unnecessary but for a proud Dragonmarked house it seems... important/prudent.

Was this  or any similar situation ever addressed in any official material?

As splat books appear silent on the issue, knowledge of any published Eberron novels addressing the issue would be the only likely source (if any exists at all... which admittedly it may not). Hopefully there's a bookworm out here with insight to its (non)existence?

Comment: I'm confused what the question is, exactly. It starts about House Deneith, but the end of it pretty much sums up to "how do mercenaries prevent being sent as cannon fodder", I don't see how House Deneith is any different in that regard than normal mercs.

Comment: @Theik Mercenaries in general might have multiple different reactions to this kind of thing. The question is about what measures *House Deneith specifically* utilizes, as described in official material. In other words, it’s the difference between “what *could* mercenaries do about this?” and “what *does Deneith actually do* about this?” The former question would be closed as too-broad, off-topic, and quite possibly primarily opinion-based. The latter is a well-scoped, on-topic question.

Comment: Is there something in the Deneith code like *Never turn down a job* or *Always see a job through to the end* or something? If not, then your question may contain the seed of a decent self-answer: even seriously hardcore military contractors aren't *suicidal* about getting the job done!

Comment: I misread the title of this question as "How did House Deneith prevent moss lasses?" and found myself wondering if they had some kind of dryad problem.

Answer (score 7):

I don’t believe that official materials discuss this at all. Certainly, *Eberron Campaign Setting*, *Player’s Guide to Eberron*, *Dragonmarked*, and *The Forge of War*, by far the supplements most likely to discuss it, do not.

Comment: Having flipped through those quickly, I'm inclined to agree. Anything we could answer here would be supposition

Comment: For such a strange situation I figured this may be the answer. However, would eberron novels be considered canon/in scope for the purposes of RPG.SE?

Comment: @Ben-Jamin They would! But I haven’t read them and don’t own them, so I can’t answer whether or not they include such information. If someone were to answer with that information, I would certainly upvote—and if the answer were “yes, they have that information,” I would also delete my answer.